# Java System rules EnvironmentVariables variables is null after set some values

Tags: java, junit, properties, environment-variables

I have to setup some environmental variables and properties values in my uniTtest, I'm following the example defined in `https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/`

It is how my class looks like:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.EnvironmentVariables;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class EnvironmentVariablesTest
{
  @Rule
  public final EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables
      = new EnvironmentVariables();

  @Test
  public void setEnvironmentVariable() {
    environmentVariables.set("name", "value");
    assertEquals("value", System.getenv("name"));
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the next error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :value
Actual   :null
```

I also added the next dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
      <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <!-- using junit:junit instead -->
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I can't figure out what is the error in this example, or what I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` is using JUnit 5's `Test` annotation not JUnit 4's - replace the import for `import org.junit.Test;`, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same issue. It worked for version 1.17.2, but going to 1.18.0 or 1.19.0, the environment variables become null.

I don't know why yet. Downgrading your version to 1.17.2 will work though.